# Are natural logs, natural in any sense?

Tags: logarithms

are natural logarithms of a number natural in any sense? Why are they called natural when the base is e and common when the base is 10?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Origin_of_the_term_natural_logarithm

Comment: I wonder if you have [done any research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm#Origin_of_the_term_natural_logarithm) before asking this question.

Comment: No, I haven't. I just read the Wikipedia page referred by Ron.

Comment: Well, maybe in the future you can take a few minutes to try on your own. This will prevent your questions being put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Part of this involves calculus reasons, namely that the derivative of $\ln(x)$ is $1/x$, a claim other logarithms cannot make; so $\ln$ is a "unique" logarithm. Moreover, it's the inverse of $e^x$, which is also special among exponential functions, again for calculus reasons (it is its own derivative).

Comment: Yes, that's what I found on Wikipedia